# write matrices to file including colnames

Tags: r

I would like to combine two matrices and write them into a file while inserting their colnames into the file like this:

```
    Cats Dogs Mice
    3    7    9
    Bananas Apples Melons
    10      2      8
```

How would I do that in an elegant way? Thank you !

Comment: You can try `write.table` with `append=TRUE`

Comment: Thanks - but seems only to work for colnames of the first matrix in the data frame

Comment: Do you have a data.frame or matrix?.  This is what I tried `write.table(df1, 'rkay.txt', quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE);
 write.table(df2, 'rkay.txt', quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)`  It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks - this way it worked! The reason why it didn't work for me whas that I ran `matrix.list <- list(df1, df2); data <- do.call(rbind, matrix.list); write.table(data, file ="data.txt",  append = T, quote = F, sep = "\t", row.names = F)`

Comment: Why?  That's going to be nothing but problems when you work on it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `write.table` with `append=TRUE`.  Suppose if the two datasets are 'df1' and 'df2'.

```
 write.table(df1, 'rkay.txt', quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
 write.table(df2, 'rkay.txt', quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)

  read.table('rkay.txt')
  #     V1     V2     V3
  #1    Cats   Dogs   Mice
  #2       3      7      9
  #3 Bananas Apples Melons
  #4      10      2      8
```